# VSCODE Extension for PHP 5

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I am working on an old project which is based on PHP5. I am using PHP intelephense as the VsCode extesnion but it showing me error lines in all the mysql functions because of mysqli funtions. Can anyone suggest me a good PHP extension for PHP5 or can I fix this issue in my existing PHP intelephense extension.?

I have tried to so many things like changing php verion from my local but that didn't for me.

Comment: clone the repo of the extension, checkout a version that supports PHP5, change the name /creator of the extension, package the extension, install it from the Extension Bar top menu (`...`)

Comment: mysqli still exists in PHP5, and it's much safer when used properly. I'd say go about changing all of the mysql functions to mysqli

Comment: This extension supports PHP 5, or at least it did until recently. Anyway, the mysql_* stubs should still be available regardless of whether PHP 5 is supported or not.